# How to display attributes of object when using jbuilder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jbuilder

I want to show an employee, and all of their reports like the following:

```
{
name :'ceo'
salary: '1000000'
directs:
    {
        name: 'sally',
        salary: '100000'
    },
    {
        name: 'phil',
        salary: '100000'
    }
}
```

I must have a defect such that I only get everything under `directs`.  Here's the jbuilder code for the `show` action:

```
json.extract! @employee, :name, :salary

json.array! @employee.direct_reports do |d|
    json.name d.name
    json.salary d.salary
end
```

I've tried several iterations of the first part of the code, but I continually see the following on a rest call, for example `http://localhost:3000/employees/1.json`:

```
[    
    {
        name: 'sally',
        salary: '100000'
    },
    {
        name: 'phil',
        salary: '100000'
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have `respond_to :json` inside the respective controller and you have set `@employee` variable right.

Also try stopping and starting the rails application.

Check out this jbuilder snippet:

```
json.extract! @employee, :name, :salary

json.directs @employee.direct_reports do |d|
  json.name d.name
  json.salary d.salary
end
```

Comment: Thanks, but the page is rendering so I know the jbuilder is being executed.

Comment: I've updated the answer with a jbuilder snippet. Please try it out.

Answer (score 0):

to get this:

```
    {
name :'ceo'
salary: '1000000'
directs:
    {
        name: 'sally',
        salary: '100000'
    },
    {
        name: 'phil',
        salary: '100000'
    }
}
```

you need

```
json.extract! @employee, :name, :salary
json.name :name
json.salary :salary


json.array! @employee.direct_reports do |d|
    json.name d.name
    json.salary d.salary
end
```

Comment: I would really expect this to work but it doesn't.  If I remove the array! portion and change the top part so that each symbol is referenced as an attribute of the `@employee`, then it prints the appropriate data for the top level.  However, with both pieces present, I only get the array.